# connect R to MySQL with RODBC using dsn

Tags: mysql, r, dsn, rodbc

**Short version:**  I'm trying to figure out how to use the dsn argument in the `odbcConnect()` function to connect to a MySQL database.

**Longer version:**  I appologize if this is an ignorant question.  I didn't find an answer on SO searching under the tags.  I'm not new to R, although I'm not the world's foremost expert.  I am new to MySQL.  I have been trying to learn it on my own.

I would like to be able to create tables and such in R and write them to a database in MySQL and then be able to select from them later and read the selected records back into R for analysis.  I can create a database in MySQL, select, export a text file, & read that file into R now, but I would rather be able to do everything from R.  For this purpose, I installed RODBC to be able to connect R to MySQL directly.  I understand that I need to use the `odbcConnect()` function, but I do not understand what to put for the dsn argument to do this, and haven't been able to figure it out from the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Source_Name) or the [help file](http://127.0.0.1:45869/help/library/RODBC/html/odbcConnect.html).

**Details** (if needed):

```
I did not establish a uid or password when I set up MySQL

Versions used:          Windows XP;     R 2.10.1;     MySQL 5.5
Locations of exe files: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin  
                        C:\Program Files\R\R-2.10.1\bin
```

I expect I need fairly basic advice--e.g., it might be best to assume I don't even know what dsn stands for (even though that's not actually true).  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific problem may be, but the **RODBC** package has a spectacularly detailed [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf) regarding setting up DSNs and basic usage.

Comment: @joran, thanks for your help. I had skimmed the beginning of the vignette, but missed the mention of the appendix. I just read it.  It recommends setting up a dsn using Microsoft ODBC Administrator under administrator tools. I brought that up, but it doesn't have an option for MySQL; should I use the Microsoft dBase driver (*.dbf) or something else, is there a way to get an option for MySQL?

Comment: I think you should read the section of the vignette titled "Sources of drivers" if you are missing a MySQL ODBC driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution I can suggest would be installing [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html).  This will give you native connectivity to the MySQL database that you are using.

If you want to use ODBC besides needing to have the [MySQL ODBC drivers](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) you will need to set up the ODBC connection in the ODBC manager on Windows XP.  When you go through the connection it will ask you for a name, which will be your DSN name, which then you should be able to use in `odbcConnect()`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I started with RMySQL, but could never get it to work. There are half a dozen questions on SO on how to set up RMySQL, they differ from each other, & none of them got it to work on my machine. Several suggested RODBC was easier to work with, that's why I'm here now. Using the driver link you provide, I downloaded and installed the 5.1.10 connector. It is here: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.1`. Now what do I do? I'm at a bit of a loss. I think I need pretty basic information.

Comment: `Control Panel -> Administrative Tools ->Data Sources`.  And set up your access there.  The name you will give it will be your DSN.  I am not sure if you have an issue on Windows but On Linux I had it working like a charm.

Comment: I went there and it pops up a window. MySQL is not listed under the initial tab 'User DSN'; if I click on the 'Drivers' tab, 'MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver' is listed at the bottom (if you scroll down); double clicking it does nothing; clicking OK makes the window go away, but otherwise appears to do nothing. It does not ask me for a name, or provide any guidance.

Comment: On User DSN you have to do `Add` and configure access using `MySQL Driver`

Comment: I think was basic enough... It seems to have worked. However, in R `sqlTables()` returns nothing, whereas at the prompt in MySQL, `show databases` returns several, each of which have tables. Will this connection only let me access tables I made in R and wrote to MySQL? or did I make an error somewhere? (I didn't enter anything for any of the other fields besides name; there's a 'database' field w/ a drop-down menu, but not all of the databases listed in MySQL are shown there.)

Comment: This is probably another question altogether because all details are needed to answer it.  Including how you call it, output of MySQL command line, etc.  And it probably better to for superuser.com

Comment: That's fair. Thanks for all your help and patience!