# R connect to database

Tags: r, database, rodbc

Sorry but I am failing at a very simple task right now.

I have the following database information:

- database name
- hostname
- port
- SID
- TNS
- User ID
- password

I want to build a connection with the RODBC package.
According to the results of my google search i should do

```
conn<-odbcConnect(dsn, uid=***, pwd=***)
```

what is "dsn"? is this even the right way?

Comment: What are you working on? Windows, linux or what?

Comment: DSN = data source name. You need to set this up. Outside R. Or see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539544/connect-r-to-mysql-with-rodbc-using-dsn

Comment: i use windows. i can connect to the database with Oracle SQL developer without a problem. I was just wondering how i can do this directly with R. Right now i use Oracle SQL developer to extract .csv files and load them into R.

Answer (score 1):

`dsn` is Data Source Name, which is a shortcut you may define on your machine to store key information about the connection.  How you set up a DSN varies depending on your operating system.

I write scripts that run on multiple machines, so rather than use a DSN, I use `odbcDriverConnect`, via something like

```
odbcDriverConnect(connection="driver=[driver]; server=[server]; database=[database]; uid = [User ID]; pwd = [password]")
```

You'll need to know your driver name to make this work.  Where to find this will depend on your operating system, as well as the flavor of SQL you are using.